# How to change values in pandas database column based on values in same column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame that is extremely large.

Basically, I want all the same weeks that have even one Yes to be changed to Yes, even if they specifically do not have a yes value but share the characteristic week.

Below is a small example that explains what I want (sorry for the formatting I am new to stack overflow)

Current:

```
 Week | Output
 1     Yes
 2     No
 3     No
 1     No
 2     Yes
 3     No
```

This is what I desire:

```
 Week | Output
 1     Yes
 2     Yes
 3     No
 1     Yes
 2     Yes
 3     No
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate weeks which have at least one Output equal to "Yes". Then use `pd.DataFrame.loc` to update values:

```
# get array of weeks in scope
yes_weeks = df.loc[df['Output'] == 'Yes', 'Week'].unique()

# update values conditionally
df.loc[df['Week'].isin(yes_weeks), 'Output'] = 'Yes'
```

Comment: This works! Thank you! (in the python display it appears off by one row but when I export to CSV it's perfect)

Comment: @TobeyBryant, No problem, don't forget to accept a solution that helped (green tick on left). It's also worth looking at the other `groupby` solutions if you have time.

Answer (score 1):

Using `any`

```
df.loc[df.Output.eq('Yes').groupby(df['Week']).transform('any'),'Output']='Yes'
df
Out[534]: 
   Week Output
0     1    Yes
1     2    Yes
2     3     No
3     1    Yes
4     2    Yes
5     3     No
```